# angularjs Array push Not working in switch statement

Tags: angularjs, arrays, push

**Angular js** Push array not working in switch case it update last added element only

```
   vm.saveModalData = function(title) {            
        if (!$scope.parentCtrl.docsList[vm.newDocObj.document_category]){
          $scope.parentCtrl.docsList[vm.newDocObj.document_category] = [];
        }
        if(!title){
        title = vm.docFileName;
        $scope.parentCtrl.docsList[vm.newDocObj.document_category].push(vm.docFileName);
        } else {
          $scope.parentCtrl.docsList[vm.newDocObj.document_category].push(title);
        }
        var doc_obj = {};
        doc_obj.title = title;
        doc_obj.type = appConstants.DOCUMENT_CATEGORY[selectedCategory];
        doc_obj.data = vm.newDocObj.document;
        switch(selectedCategory) {
          case 'PAN':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.pan_document = true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+1].enabled=true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+2].enabled=true;
            break;
          case 'Aadhaar':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.aadhar_document = true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+1].enabled=true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+2].enabled=true;
            break;
          case 'Driving License':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.driving_license_document = true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+1].enabled=true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+2].enabled=true;
            break;
          case 'Passport':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.passport_document = true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+1].enabled=true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+2].enabled=true;
            break;
          case 'Voter Id':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.voter_id_document = true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+1].enabled=true;
            $scope.parentCtrl.tabsList[$scope.parentCtrl.activeTab+2].enabled=true;
            break;
          case 'Company IT Returns':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            break;
          case 'Company PAN':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            break;
          case 'ITR/VAT Returns/ST Returns':
            $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
            break;
          case 'Other':
          $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(doc_obj);
          break;
          default:
            break;
        }

        vm.closeModal();
      }
```

How to fix this issue?

I try to add first document it added into array then i added one more document but it remove existing and add as a new.

Comment: did you got any error in console?

Comment: No error if i upload one more previous one remove and new one updated

Comment: $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents = []; I think your array is empty every time while upload.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this,

You are calling docCtrl.openAddDocModal(doc) function, while adding each and every time of Document add. Inside that function only you have initialised your array.

```
$scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents = [];
```

so that each and every time it's getting reinitialised with empty.

Add this code line out side of the $uibModal.open(), recommended add below  `$scope.arr = [];`

hope it will work...

Comment: @Develop if possible, can u make a fiddle for this code?

Comment: Can you please tell me what i need to do in this. Shall i remove this or what $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents = [];

Comment: yes, Your array initialisation place is wrong..  Need to check where we have to initialise it correctly. Make a fiddle and share the link will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your array in parent controller and use $emit on $on for passing data between child to parent controller. Try like below.

```
 function docLpController($scope, $q, appConstants, $uibModal, utils) {
    var vm = this;
$scope.parentCtrl = $scope.$parent.finwizzCtrl;
```

`$scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents = []; // declared`

```
$scope.$on('sendData', function (event, data) {
      $scope.parentCtrl.completeDetails.documents.push(data);
    });

vm.saveModalData = function(title){
        $scope.$emit('sendData', doc_obj);
}
```